# How do I turn pandas DataFrame groupby results into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what I have done:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'in':[2, 2, 3, 4], 'out':[2,2,4,4]})
in_out=df.groupby(['in','out']).size()
```

I got results:

```
in  out
2   2      2
3   4      1
4   4      1
dtype: int64
```

How do I turn the results into a dataframe with columns in, out and count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `name`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'in':[2, 2, 3, 4], 'out':[2,2,4,4]})
in_out=df.groupby(['in','out']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print in_out
   in  out  count
0   2    2      2
1   3    4      1
2   4    4      1
```